# Missing data in the plot using ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am a bit confused with ggplot2. I plotted my data and have some missing data in the plot but not at the legend. I actually have 40 groups (FID) to be plotted and some are missing. My code is:

```
Data48a <- read.table("Data48a.eigenvec", header = T, sep = "")

PlotData48a <- ggplot(Data48a, aes(x= PC1,y= PC2, group= FID, shape= FID, color= FID))

PlotData48a + geom_point(aes(color=FID)) +
   geom_hline(aes(yintercept=0)) + geom_vline(aes(xintercept=0))+
   scale_shape_manual(values=1:nlevels(Data48a$FID)) +
   scale_color_manual(values=1:nlevels(Data48a$FID)) + 
   coord_equal(ratio = 1)
```

and here is the error:

```
In grid.Call.graphics(L_points, x$x, x$y, x$pch, x$size) : unimplemented pch value '28'
```

My data is like:

```
FID IID PC1 PC2 PC3    
Ami AX-AM-013607-1-01 0.0302889 -0.0236855 0.0294569    
Ami AX-AM-013608-1-01 0.0346382 -0.0232841 0.0175366    
Ami AX-AM-013609-1-01 0.0396438 -0.0157996 0.0163948    
Ami AX-AM-013610-1-01 0.0386903 -0.017313 0.0146025    
Ami AX-AM-013611-1-01 0.0382764 -0.0151733 0.0222798    
Ami AX-AM-013613-1-01 0.0416853 -0.00826403 0.0245685    
Ami AX-AM-013614-1-01 0.0388888 -0.0113679 0.0281065    
Ami AX-AM-013615-1-01 0.0438035 -0.0102871 0.0156296    
Ami AX-AM-013616-1-01 0.0364263 -0.0211585 0.0246802    
BatakKaro ID-KR-000001-1-01 0.0321929 0.00520535 0.00480784    
BatakKaro ID-KR-000002-1-01 0.0345291 -0.00101008 -0.00264379    
BatakKaro ID-KR-000012-1-01 0.0352078 -0.000998926 -0.00847158    
BatakKaro ID-KR-000014-1-01 0.0306035 -0.00150602 -0.00365927
```

Comment: when  sharing data please try using dput so people can just copy paste your object

Comment: there are two many levels of FID, so it cannot find a unique shape for each.

Comment: Thank you all for your answer. I reduced the number of the group to make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will solve your entire problem, but this should highlight the source of your error.

You are trying to plot 40 levels of data or groups, but there are only 25 plotting characters (pch). In order to remove the errors I think you'd have to limit the number of groups the 25 or less.

```
require(ggplot2)

# no error
xx = 1:25
ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x = xx,y = xx), col=xx,shape=xx)

# error
xx = 1:26
ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x = xx,y = xx), col=xx,shape=xx)
```

Comment: Thank you all for your answer. I reduced the number of the group to make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

unimplemented pch value '28':

Legal shape values are the numbers 0 to 25, and the numbers 32 to 127.

It seems you have 40 shapes (0..39)?

See also http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/shape

Comment: Thank you RDW. I did not understand how exactly to use the script especially those defining the x and y axes to be related at the shapes